# What organic molecule, if any, does this diagram represent in Louis CK's "Louie" Season Four, Episode Eleven, just before the six minute mark?

Tags: organic-chemistry, identification

I'm wondering what molecule this is, if any, and whether this molecule is even physically likely or possible.

Here is a screenshot of the scene from "Louie" (a hilarious and fascinating comedy drama series by Louis "the comic's comic" CK premiered in 2014 in the United States, ):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

As andselisk states in the comments, it is adenine.

> [OP] I suspect it is fake.

No, it is as real as water and the stars. What makes this a little bit complicated is how to draw it, specifically on which nitrogen (N) to put the hydrogen (H). The structure shown is the 9H adenine tautomer, supposedly the most stable tautomer.

[image]

Source: [ACS Omega 2021, 6, 29, 18890-18903](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsomega.1c02118)

Some sources show the 1H tautomer (with a hydrogen bound the nitrogen atom numbered 1), e.g. [ChemSpider](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.185.html). [Pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Adenine) shows the 7H tautomer (the second most stable form according to the above source).

> [OP in comments] Why are all your diagrams left to right reversed compared to the one displayed in the OP?

This is a flat molecule, so if you rotate it (or look at it from the other side), it appears left-to-right reversed. It is the same molecule, though. As andselisk states in the comments, there is a convention for the prefered orientation if there are no other considerations.

[image]

> [OP in comments] Is it fair to say the angles of some of the bonds in the diagram displayed in the OP are wrong?

The type of diagram shown on the board of the still is called a Lewis structure. For Lewis structures, angles can be chosen at will. For rings, most people try to draw regular hexagons and pentagons. However, a house-shaped pentagon is also popular (see below, upside down in this case, and a so-called skeletal structure with the carbon atoms implied at intersections of lines).

[image]
Source: [Sigma Alrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/644331)

#### Adenine as building block

Luckily, the adenine we care most about (as part of ATP, DNA and RNA) has a glycosidic bond at nitrogen 9 and no hydrogens directly attached to ring nitrogen atoms at all, so there is more uniformity in the molecular structures of adenosine on the web and in popular culture. Below is the structure of adenosine, with the glycosidic bond shown in blue (and the carbon atoms and most hydrogen atoms implied). In RNA and DNA, this adenosine would be linked to other building blocks via phosphodiester linkages involving its two hydroxyl groups.

[image]

> [OP in comments] Since you use the word "funny", this could be a good time to ask everyone here whether there is anything comedic, however subtly, indirectly, strangely, or darkly (CK's humor is like that, IMHO), about the diagram on the board or adenine.

Well, it shows a Lewis structure, not a Louis structure...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133716/discussion-on-answer-by-karsten-theis-what-organic-molecule-if-any-does-this-d).